# Visiting Lany or Inlemay on a cruise from Spain - single or multiple entry Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, turkey, multiple-entry, istanbul

If I am in the Schengen Visa area (with a visa) and we cruise to Turkey getting off the ship at Istanbul and Kuskadasi and return to Barcelona - do I need a multiple-entry visa or will a single entry work?

Comment: a single entry visa would not be enough.

Comment: It's probably best to ask the cruise ship company. The visa rules for Turkey are different from the rest of Europe and you will want to make sure you have everything in order. Sometimes, there are different immigration rules for passengers from cruise ships. The company obviously deals with this all the time and can advise you.

Answer (score 3):

To expand my comment - You will need a multiple entry Schengen visa. Going to Turkey means that you leave the Schengen area and you will reenter it when you return to Barcelona.